# add and/or remove li on same button click with jquery

Tags: jquery, button, click, html-lists

I have a set of buttons that all have the class '.skills'. When I click a button, I want to toggle the class 'btn-clicked' and add the button text to a li inside of a ul. This I have working. When I click the button again, I want to remove the 'btn-clicked' class (which toggle class does successfully) and remove the li from the ul. I have the following code which adds the 'btn-clicked' class and adds the li to the ul on the first click, but on the second click, it doesn't remove the li from the ul.

```
$(".skills").on("click", function() {

  var $this = $(this);
  var $ul = $('.previewSkillsRequired');
  var $btnText = $this.text();
  var $li = $('<li/>').html($btnText);

  $this.toggleClass('btn-clicked');

  if($this.hasClass('btn-clicked')) {
    $ul.append($li);
  } else {
    $ul.find($li).remove();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `var $li = $('<li/>').html($btnText);` is causing your problems. I rewrote your code to circumvent this.
In stead of finding the particular `<li>` with `html()`, you should use a `contains()` selector.

```js
$(".skills").on("click", function() {

  var $this = $(this);
  var $ul = $('.previewSkillsRequired');
  var $btnText = $this.text();

  $this.toggleClass('btn-clicked');

  if($this.hasClass('btn-clicked')) {
    $ul.append('<li>' + $btnText + '</li>');
  } else {
    $ul.find('li:contains(' + $btnText + ')').remove();
  }
  
});
```

```css
.btn-clicked {
  background-color: #33ffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="skills">Button Text</button> <button class="skills">Other Button</button>
<br>
<ul class="previewSkillsRequired">
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 2</li>
  <li>List item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I was so close. After looking at this code for close to an hour, my eyes started glazing over.

Comment: You're most welcome! jQuery is an amazing programming language, where KISS often applies :-)